# View [bcs.home.adminIndex] not found while uploading laravel 5.8 project on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting, shared

My laravel project is working fine on localhost but not working on live domain after I upload my project on shared hosting.
I have developed my laravel site on Windows machine and uploaded it on Linux machine. I have a /home route, after login users redirect to /home by checking user role. It works fine for one user named 'data entry' user but do not work for other users.

Here is my route -

```
Route::get('/home','HomeController@index')->name('index');
```

Here is my HomeController -

```
 public function index()
{
    if (auth::user()->userRole == 'super admin') {
        return view('bcs.home.superAdminIndex');
    }
    if (auth::user()->userRole == 'admin') {
        return view('bcs.home.adminIndex');
    }
    if (auth::user()->userRole == 'data entry') {
        return view('bcs.home.dataEntryIndex');
    }
    if (auth::user()->userRole == 'payment verifier') {
        return view('bcs.home.paymentVerifierIndex');
    }

}
```

Comment: other routes working fine? or what error you are getting?

Comment: @farooq Yes, other routes are working fine. Just View [bcs.home.adminIndex] and bcs.home.paymentVerifierIndex not found. But bcs.home.dataEntryIndex is showing perfect.

Comment: What is you development environment?

Comment: Xampp server on Windows machine.

Comment: So check the upper/lower case words in your file name, methods, classes and ... . I think it can solve the problem.

Comment: I checked, everything is accurate. But don't know why it works for one user and others not.